# Unable to layer HTML elements using z-index and scroll effect

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have four HTML elements, and one of them is scrolling downward with a scroll effect. I want the green-colored div to always stay above Block B but below Block C. Additionally, I need Block C to become hidden behind Block B when they overlap. Also, the darker green element should be shown the same way as Block A.

Edit: Corrected Codesandbox.
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gifted-gagarin-587ll5?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A25%2C36)

```
return (
      <div className=" h-[200vh] w-full flex flex-col items-center">

        <div className=" relative mt-[300px] bg-green-900 w-full h-[200px] text-black text-center flex flex-col justify-between text-white ">
          <div className=" relative z-10">
            Block A
          </div>
        </div>

        <Image
          src={borderSvgTexture}
          className=" relative  h-auto  w-full min-w-screen  mt-[-5px]   "
          alt=""
        />

        <div className=" bg-blue-600 w-full h-[200px] mt-[-50px]  ">
            <div className=' mt-[100px] text-center'>Block B</div>
        </div>

      <motion.div
        style={{ y }}
        className="h-[500px] flex justify-center absolute inset-x-0 mx-auto max-w-[1800px] text-white"
        >
        <div className=" w-[100px] h-[100px] bg-red-500">Block C</div>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  )
```

I've tried various z-index combinations but can't achieve the desired results, something unintended always ends up getting hidden. Now, I am not sure if this even possible.

Comment: Based on the logic, you may need more than just z-index 
Since you need Block C > Block A > Block B, but also Block B > Block C.
You may use z-index for initial element positions and use javascript for scroll tracking to add fade effects of overlap for block C.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But, not sure what do you mean by fade effects of overlap and how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a solution to this based using the `Element:getBoundingClientRect()` for identifying component scroll positions and dimensions in react.

Basically utilizing `useRef` hooks for getting the component properties, and getting the `top` and `bottom` for the `divs`. We are able to define conditions when the `Block C` `height` should shrink, expand, or `z-index` changed.

Updated: to include hiding behind the image pattern.

Take a look at the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hidden-moon-pmfck7), where I have implemented this method on a fork of your code. **Note:** On the sandbox sometimes randomly `Block C` is not visible initially.Please refresh when that happens to ensure all 3 blocks are visible, so `initialHeight` for `Block C` is properly captured

The key function is described below, this listenToScroll is called via `useEffect` whenever the user scrolls as the `scrollHandler`.

Essentially it defines three conditions, for the `Block C` and affects the `height` and `z-index` class

```
const listenToScroll = () => {
  if (cRef.current && bRef.current) {
    const cRect = cRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const bRect = bRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    const cBottom = cRect.bottom;
    const cTop = cRect.top;
    const bTop = bRect.top + (bRect.height/5); // To take image height into account
    let cHeight = cInitialHeight;

    if (cBottom > bTop && cTop < bTop){ //Case when scrolling down and C starts to overlap B
        cHeight = cRect.height - (cBottom - bTop);
        cHeight = cHeight < 0 ? 0 : cHeight;
        cHeight = cHeight + "px";
        setCStyle({...cStyle, height: cHeight})
        setCIndex("z-30");
    }
    else if (cBottom < bTop && cRect.height < cInitialHeight){ // Case when scrolling up and C starts going out and above B 
        cHeight = cRect.height + (bTop - cBottom);
        cHeight = cHeight > cInitialHeight ? cInitialHeight : cHeight;
        cHeight = cHeight + "px";
        setCStyle({...cStyle, height: cHeight})
        setCIndex("z-30");
      }
    else if(cTop > bTop){ // Case when completely inside block B
      cHeight = cInitialHeight;
      setCStyle({...cStyle, height: cHeight});
      setCIndex("z-0");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: @Zaltman this may not be the ideal solution since we are not using any libraries or optimized approach. However, this should work for the use case you have described and you can use this as a base for the next steps.

Comment: This is definitely a step in a right direction, thank you. However, the problem in this case is that the **Block C** hides behind a straight line, ideally, it should go behind that uneven blue border and I have no idea how to achieve it. I guess, that is what you meant by saying its not an ideal solution. 

I wish there would be a way to create a separate relationship of z-index between two elements, but not sure if such thing exists.

Comment: @Zaltman I have updated the sandbox link in the answer, to address where it will appear that the image is hiding behind the waves. Now the trick to do that is that you need to have the transparent part of the image facing up rather than down. So I created a `PNG`  based on your texture `SVG` where the blue part is filled in and the upper portion is transparent and gave it a higher z-index.